# Align two flex items vertically independent of each other

Tags: html, css

Inside the container are two elements "Title" and "Signature". Their vertical position will be taken from the given parameters and added to the mustache template, i.e. can be anything, for example:

- title and caption top/center/bottom;
- title at the top, caption at the center;
- title centered, caption bottom;
- title at the top, caption at the bottom, etc.

If I do it through the lines, then the captions either stick to the headings (when they are on the same vertical) or the indentation is visible along the width of the heading content. If I do through the columns - nothing happens at all. Can anyone suggest to align several elements vertically, but so that they do not stick together and do not run into each other?

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  border: 5px solid yellow;
  background-color: #bbb;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="item">
     <div class="title" style="align-self: flex-start;">Title lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum</div>
     <div class="caption" style="align-self: center;">Caption caption caption</div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="item">
     <div class="title" style="align-self: center;">Title lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum</div>
     <br>
     <div class="caption" style="align-self: center;">Caption caption caption</div>
  </div>
  
      <div class="item">
     <div class="title" style="align-self: center;">Title lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum</div>
     <br>
     <div class="caption" style="align-self: flex-end;">Caption caption caption</div>
  </div>
```

**UPD:** Added an image of how it should look like in the end
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `justify-self` and `align-self` for variant 2 and 3. Everything else is basic `flexbox` and `grid` which you can learn [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 1rem;
  gap: 1rem;
}
.variant{
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #6D6A89;
  height: 25rem;
  width: 250px;
  color: #fff;
}

.var1{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.var2{
  display: grid;
}
.var2>*{
  justify-self: center;
}

.var3{
  display: grid;
}

.var3>*{
  align-self: end;
  justify-self: center;
}

.var4{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="variant var1">
    <h1>Title top</h1>
    <div class="caption">caption top</div>
  </div>
  <div class="variant var2">
    <h1>Title top</h1>
    <div class="caption">caption center</div>
  </div>
  <div class="variant var3">
    <h1>Title center</h1>
    <div class="caption">caption bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="variant var4">
    <h1>Title top</h1>
    <div class="caption">caption bottom</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

More on `flexbox` [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: I'm afraid this is not quite what you need. I've added an image of what it should look like to the question.

Comment: edited the snippet.